# SQL getting value associated with max()

Tags: sql

```
Type | Price | Cost | Profit
----------------------------
p    |  499  |  205 |  294
t    |  349  |  132 |  217
```

I'm trying to get the type from the max of profit like:

```
Type
----
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to order the table by `Profit` descending and take the first row:

```
SELECT Type
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY Profit DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Type
FROM yourtable
WHERE Profit = (SELECT MAX(Profit) FROM yourtable)
```

or alternatively you can `JOIN` to a derived table containing `MAX(profit)`. The latter methods are more useful when you want to search over multiple maximums for different groups:

```
SELECT Type
FROM yourtable y
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Profit) AS max_profit
      FROM yourtable) mp ON mp.max_profit = y.Profit
```

In all cases for your data the output is `p`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/asJuyLd9zmggxWK13zfcfJ/1)